# When I try the print and say command on the same .pl file on separate lines it will not run and give : the error Uncaught exception from user code

Tags: perl, syntax, syntax-error, scalar, padre

I am very new to Perl and am currently just following along a youtube tutorial guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WEghIXs8F6c). First he explains the syntax for printing  varibles using print and then at roughly 8:50 in the video he explains how there's another method to printing called "say". However at this point when I try to run this code altogether I get the following pop up message:

**Hello World!
Can't use string ("curt lives on "123 main st"
") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at Hello_world.pl line 21 (#1)
(F) Only hard references are allowed by "strict refs".  Symbolic
references are disallowed.  See perlref.
Uncaught exception from user code:
Can't use string ("curt lives on "123 main st"
") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at Hello_world.pl line 21.
at Hello_world.pl line 21
Press any key to continue . . .**

to preface, this is the line of code I have used so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
use feature "switch";
use v5.12.3;
print " Hello World!\n";
my $name = 'curt';
my ($age, $street) = (40, '123 main st');
my $my_info = "$name lives on \"$street\"\n";
print $my_info
my $bunch_of_info = <<"END";
This is 
a lot of information
for different lines
END
say $bunch_of_info
```

I appreciate any and all help. Thankyou very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have

```perl
print $my_info
my $bunch_of_info = ...;
```

The missing semi-colon means `$my_info` is expected to be a file handle.

```perl
print $fh ...;
```

A file handle can be a reference to a glob that contains a file handle. The string `123 main st` is technically a valid reference, except when strictures (specifically `strict refs`) are enabled. And thus, you get the error you got.

Answer (score -1):

Please see corrected code and compare with your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use feature 'say';
use feature "switch";
use v5.12.3;

print " Hello World!\n";

my $name = 'curt';
my ($age, $street) = (40, '123 main st');
my $my_info = "$name lives on \"$street\"\n";

print $my_info;

my $bunch_of_info = <<"END";
This is
a lot of information
for different lines
END

say $bunch_of_info;
```

Output

```
 Hello World!
curt lives on "123 main st"
This is
a lot of information
for different lines
```

Comment: hahahaha was that all it was. I would never have spotted that thanks very much!

Comment: @jamalsaya Did you put this comment on the wrong answer?

Comment: @TLP The comment was posted before my answer.

Comment: @ikegami That might explain it.